# Swift: Show UIAlertController in didReceiveLocalNotification method

Tags: swift2, uialertview, uialertcontroller, localnotification

I want to show alert when notification is fired while app is running, here is [tutorial](https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/implementing-local-notifications-in-ios-8-swift/) which i used for local notifications. In tutorial, it uses `UIAlertView` to show alert and it works, here is code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    // Point for handling the local notification when the app is open.
    // Showing reminder details in an alertview
    UIAlertView(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
}
```

but it gives warning that UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 9, so i used `UIAlertController`, but when i run it it gives warning:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7c322a00> on <xxx> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here is my `didReceiveLocalNotification` method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: notification.alertBody, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
    }))

    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How i can show UIAlertController in `didReceiveLocalNotification` method? I also tried:

```
 let activeViewCont = application.windows[0].rootViewController?.presentedViewController
 activeViewCont!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `self.window.rootViewController` is this a navigation controller in your project?

Comment: @Nishant no, i didn't use navigation controller on my project. `self.window.rootViewController` is returns my SplashScreen where i created my own splash screen, it downloads data when app is opening for first time. But i need to get current showing view controller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

    var topController : UIViewController = (application.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!

    while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil) {

        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: notification.alertBody, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in}))

    topController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i also tried this before, it does not help too. it gives same error: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController> on <MyProject.SplashScreenViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: I think i need to find current showing view controller, but i don't know how, for example, when i get that warning, app wasn't showing splash screen, it was showing another view controller

Comment: thanks the solution in link which you provided solved my issue

Comment: @kakajan: great. I have modified my code to the right answer.

Comment: thanks for help, i accepted and upvote your answer ;)

Comment: anyway this is a working solution great, but can you please summarize exactly why the op's getting warning and me too, plus one for you.